# Pre-Update method doesn't get invoked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, blob, jbpm

We have migrated spring (from "3.1.1.RELEASE" to "5.3.20") & hibernate ("3.6.9.Final" to "5.6.9.Final") whereas JBPM remains same version("5.4.0.Final"). Due to hibernate upgrade the blob type in the file "ProcessInstanceInfo.hbm.xml" doesn't support it. So I have changed the blob type from "org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveByteArrayBlobType" to "org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType" in ProcessInstanceInfo.hbm.xml. After the change, the "@Pre-Update" method doesn't get invoked due to which the process instance blob is not updated (Set as NULL in the database) which impacts the task creation i.e task cannot be created. We have planned to upgrade the JBPM later.

Comment: which version of jbpm do you target for your upgrade FYI latest jbpm support hibernate - 5.3.20.Final - reference: https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap/blob/main/pom.xml

Comment: We are using JBPM version "5.4.0.Final" & Drools version "5.5.0.Final". Which version we should choose for the upgrade activity(latest or version lower than the latest). Do we have any scripts to upgrade from "5.4.0.Final" to the suggested version? if so could you share those details?

Comment: Do we have any scripts to upgrade from "JBPM 5.4.0.Final" to the latest version? if so could you share those details?

Comment: db scripts you can find here - https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/tree/main/jbpm-db-scripts/src/main/resources/db : apply till the version you're targetting for update. i would suggest to downgrade your hibernate version to what is currently supported